# xaml how to create a trigger for textbox? active when typing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textbox, i want add a trigger, when i click that textbox, the textbox will change border color, untill typing is finish
please help me useing xaml

Comment: You mean you want the border color to be different while the textbox is focussed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a Trigger but a different styling for the Focused state would be my preferred way of doing this